# What is the django managment directory for other than holding the commands directory?

Tags: django

In our django project we've created quite a bit of custom management commands over time. All of these are nested under:

`root/<app_name>/management/commands/<command_name>.py`

The management directory contains just an `__init__.py` and the commands directory ( as specified in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/)).
This seems like unnecessary nesting to me.
Are there any other uses for the management directory that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get direct answer for that, but here are few things I collected:

1. *Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!* - The Zen Of Python
2. Future features can be added without the pollution of the root directory.
3. Makes your project organized(actually forces you, so if you are new user, you get a nice structure. You can put your own logic in `management`)
4. If you search on the web you'll find people saying that you should put your signals in the management directory.
5. Seems you can use `management.py` rather than a directory like [django built-in `sites` app](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sites/management.py).